# How to fix ERROR: "TypeError: set_default_backend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend_name'"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gnn

I'm implementing a research paper titled "G-Meta: Graph Meta Learning via Local Subgraphs.

" but whenever i run this

```
 "!python train.py --data_dir /content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv --task_setup Disjoint" command it gives an error which is this "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/G-Meta/G-Meta/train.py", line 10, in <module>
    dgl.backend.set_default_backend('pytorch')

TypeError: set_default_backend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend_name'"
```

If there is any expert please fix it by answering to this question?

I'm trying to complete a research paper implementation today, I'm expecting quick and accurate answers.

Comment: You'd need to provide us with a [minimal, reproducible error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to help you out. It would also be beneficial if you provide us with the entire traceback.

However, given the current information, I would assume that you need to explicitly write `dgl.backend.set_default_backend(backend_name='pytorch')` in line 10 of `train.py` to resolve the current error.

Comment: Without seeing the code, all that one can say is that you need to follow the functions singanture for it to work correctly (as expected).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.